# Перестановка чисел в массиве

Tags: c++, алгоритм

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    long long arr1[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> arr1[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int k = i; k < n; k++) {
            if (arr1[k] % 2 == 0) {
                long long t = arr1[k];
                arr1[k] = arr1[i];
                arr1[i] = t;
            }
        }
        cout << arr1[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Нужно переставить чётные и нечётные числа в массиве так, чтобы чётные были в начале, а нечётные только после них. Последовательность должна сохраняться

Числа переставляются но последовательность не сохраняется, прошу о помощи

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это же С++, так что в одну строку -

```
stable_sort(arr1,arr1+n,[](auto a, auto b) { return abs(a)%2 < abs(b)%2; });
```

Если я правильно понял ваше "последовательность должна сохраняться"...

Comment: Неправильно работает с отрицательными нечётными числами

Comment: Взял в ретурне а и б в модуль, сработало, спасибо

Comment: Да, логично, забыл об отрицательных...Вы правы.

Comment: А `return (a & 1) < (b & 1)` не лучше? Впрочем, на фоне stable_sort для такой задачки (потом удивляемся, чего это компы с такими гигагерцами и гигабайтами так тормозят?) это наверное уже все равно...

Comment: @avp Это все равно для такой задачки - которая вряд ли будет многомиллионного размера... Впрочем, в данном случае претендую на решение попроще, а не эффективнее :)

Comment: @Harry, своим примером мы формируем образ мышления у окружающих

Comment: @avp Увы, хотел - но не могу удалить свой ответ, как принятый... Давайте вы напишете свое решение, ТС примет его, а я свой тогда удалю...

Comment: @Harry, нет проблем (хотя я уверен, что ТС мой ответ не оценит)

Comment: @avp OK, оценю я. Но я ожидал решения O(n) только по времени, но не еще и по памяти :) Хотя не уверен, как такое написать...

Comment: Если бы был простой способ сделать stable_partition без дополнительной памяти за линейное время, мы бы получили stable qsort inplace. А этого не наблюдается. Вообще inplace stable sort без дополнительной памяти - трудная задача.

Comment: @Harry, без дополнительной памяти ничего кроме квадратичной insertion sort у меня не вырисовывается (-

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

void print_arr (long long a[], size_t n)
{
  for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << a[i] << ' ';
  cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  long long arr1[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr1[i] = random() % 100;
    if (random() % 100 > 49)
      arr1[i] = -arr1[i];
  }

  print_arr(arr1, n);

  long long *t = (__typeof__(t))malloc(n * sizeof(t[0]));
  size_t j = 0, k = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    if (arr1[i] & 1LL) // odd number
      t[k++] = arr1[i];
    else
      arr1[j++] = arr1[i];

  print_arr(arr1, j);
  print_arr(t, k);

  for (size_t i  = 0; j < n; j++)
    arr1[j] = t[i++];
  free(t);
  
  print_arr(arr1, n);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[stable_partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) решает задачу за линейное время если есть дополнительная память и за NlogN если её нет.

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror stable-partition.cpp

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    std::vector<long long> a;

    std::copy_n(
        std::istream_iterator<long long>(std::cin),
        n,
        std::back_inserter(a)
    );

    std::stable_partition(
        a.begin(),
        a.end(),
        [](long long v) { return v % 2 == 0; }
    );

    std::copy(
        a.begin(),
        a.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<long long>(std::cout, " ")
    );
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror stable-partition.cpp
> $ echo 11 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 -1 -2 | ./a.out 
> 2 4 6 8 -2 1 3 5 7 9 -1
> ```

Пара замечаний

Стандартный C++ не содержит [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Это про строку `long long arr1[n];`, где `n` не константа. GCC поддерживает их как расширение, но [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) тут уместнее.

Раз уж у нас тут такой C++ образовался, то читать/писать массивы тоже логичнее без циклов.